# Choose one observable based on condition

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I am writing an ng2 app and use an application state service based on behavior subjects that expose observables. For the majority of the use cases I want to use observable A to look up a nested object.  I found an odd case where Observable A won't have this data but its in Observable B. Observable A & B are both available from my application state service.

Right now in my component it looks like this

```
  sharedState: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private appStateService: AppStateService) {
    this.sharedState = appStateService.shared$;
  }
```

Then in my view :

```
<div>{{ (sharedState | async)?.loadedAccountDetails?.accountId }}</div>
```

As one example. What I imagine I need to do now in the component is:

1. Subscribe to Observable A and check if it has my loadedAccountDetails and account Id etc
2. If A doesn't have this value then go with B

What I was hoping to do in the component as well was only expose/have one instance variable that is an Observable so that I can keep my view/html the same.

Even if you are unfamiliar with Angular 2 I can work on that but need help understanding how to almost implement an if statement with observables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Observable
  // When any of the inner observables emit, supply latest from all
  .combineLatest(observableA, observableB)
  // Emit either result
  .map(([resultA, resultB]) => resultA || resultB)
  // Test it
  .subscribe(console.info)
```

Just make sure `observableA/B` doesn't emit anything if it doesn't find what you're looking for (use `.filter(Boolean)`, for example).

Comment: so when you map (just trying to understand your comments) are you subscribing to the observables to pull their values ...Is that what resultA/b are ?

Comment: @Barry Yep, `resultA/B` are what `observableA/B` emit. See examples in docs: [combineLatest](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-combineLatest)

Comment: so once I do my map  I 'know' which Observable I want to choose etc ..can you further explain the ```take(1)``` ? My thinking is inside map logic I can set my exposed instance variable to the correct observable and be complete but do I need to do anything to stop this chain?

Comment: map just converts the values based on whatever you pass it. It's not subscribing, but adding another stage to the production line - subscribe starts the production line.

Comment: @Sasca I don't think that's right. You either need to accept an array of the two items in `map` or provide the two-argument mapping function as a third argument to `combineLatest`. The function passed to `map` only ever takes one argument.

Comment: @RichardSzalay, You're right it should be array of values, I'll update the answer..

Comment: @Barry You don't actually need `take()` here.

Comment: ok I took it out and its working great ! thank you  - I really appreciate the follow up on my comments

Comment: what will happen if observableA/observableB didn't emit any value?

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to consider `amb`, which uses whichever observable emits a value first and unsubscribes from the second:

```
Observable.amb(
    firstSource.filter(x => x.loadedAccountDetails),
    secondSource.filter(x => x.loadedAccountDetails)
)
.subscribe(x => { })
```